# library input class not working in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restserver

I'm working with codeigniter REST API. In my API call i'm trying to get value from `$this->input->get('id')` but does not get any value from the get.

```
public function data_get($id_param = NULL){ 

    $id = $this->input->get('id');

    if($id===NULL){
        $id = $id_param;
    }
    if ($id === NULL)
    {
        $data = $this->Make_model->read($id);
        if ($data)
        {

            $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); 
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'error' => 'No record found'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); 
        }
    }
    $data = $this->Make_model->read($id);
    if ($data)
    {
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);   
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set_response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'error' => 'Record could not be found'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); 
    }
 }
```

In the above code $id doesn't return any value.

Comment: Please provide your code snippet so that we can provide exact solution.

Comment: then why use this `$id_param = NULL` in `data_get($id_param = NULL)`

Comment: if $id is empty then i'm assigning $id_param to $id

Comment: your method need some changes to get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use either `$this->input->get('id')` or `$this->get('id')` both should work

Your `data_get` method should be like this :

```
public function data_get($id_param = NULL)
{ 

    $id = ! empty($id_param) ? $id_param : $this->input->get('id');
    /* 
     u can also use this
     $id = ! empty($id_param) ? $id_param : $this->get('id');
    */
    if ($id)
    {
        $data = $this->Make_model->read($id);
        if ($data)
        {

            $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); 
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'error' => 'No record found'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'error' => 'No id is found'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code from `$id = $this->input->get('id');` to `$id = $this->get('id');`
This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've changed to $id = $this->get('id'); but not working